# Find the size of a MQTT packet in python

Tags: python, size, mqtt, packet, payload

My question is, how can i find the size of an mqtt packet  which include the control header, packet length, variable length header and payload .

At the moment i am using getsizeof to find it.

My data is in the form : b'{"0":294.3875741324,"1":292.1924140501}'

Below you can find the equation i am using to find the size of the payload.
payload_size=getsizeof(msg.payload)

The size I receive using this is 72
My question, is this method correct or is there any other way to find the size of the mqtt packet.

I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: print the message instead of sending it and just use len probably should work i would think ...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? You can calculate the size of the packet by reading the spec and understanding how the header is built (it really isn't complicated) But without knowing a LOT more information (e.g. MQTT protocol version, the topic the message is to be published to, what flags are set, any other MQTTv5 properties) we can't answer.  And the Paho library won't tell you the size of the packet

Comment: Protocol version is MQTT V3.1 (legacy).The topic is 'test/topic'.
I will attach some images in the question. @hardillb

Comment: The question is about python, not Node-RED so I'm not sure what use the images are supposed to be? As I previously stated the only way to get the full packet size is to calculate it by hand using the spec as a guide. You have also not answered why you think you need this information.

Comment: i gave the screenshot so that you could see the protocol and topic i have set .
I need the packet size to use it in a packet scheduling algorithm.
Appreciate if you could explain me how to calculate it by hand or in python.

Comment: Take a look at the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718037), it sets out the contents of the packet pretty clearly; 2+ byte header (size increases as total size increases see [Remaining Length](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718023)), 2 bytes topic length, topic, 2 bytes packet id, message. You could just copy/modify the [paho code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L2669) and take a length of the generated `bytearray`. Note this is 3.1.1 but 3.1 is the same.